# Can't execute any python program on visual code

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a python program (this time a Jupyter notebook file ipynb)
When I'm trying to execute the file or any cell it ask me to select a kernel. I have all the relevant extension installed (Python, Jupyter) and also have the updated version of Python on my PC (Python 3.11.5), I tried to change the path in the environment variables but nothing fixed the problem.
Also tried to select other interpreters and also problem was not solved.

[image: Kernel]

[image: Interpreter menu]

I'm really out of solutions and I will be happy to get some help to resolve this issue :)

Comment: What is the problem ? What is happening ? You did not describe the problem itself.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Itération122442 The problem is that I can't execute the code since it's asking me to choose a kernel I already tried to select one and also change the interpreter and I'm still facing this problem

Answer (score 3):

I think there are a few things you could try:

### Create an Environment

I'm not sure if you have already done this, or other similar steps, but you may want to create a virtual environment to install python packages in. This will not touch your original version of Python and can be extended with any packages you need. If you happen to mess something up, you can delete it and recreate it again without worrying about redownloading Python. I lean towards using `venv` which comes with Python. ie `python -m venv .virtualenv` You can see [more information here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

### Select Interpreter

As you mentioned, you've done this already, but I recommend using the first option in your screenshot "+ Enter Interpreter Path".  This will open an explorer window and you can select the interpreter. If you created a new env in the step above, you can select that. Currently it looks like you were selecting one in `~\AppData\LocalMicrosoft...` so it might be good to follow that so you can see which interpreter you are actually selecting (and making sure there isn't another environment you'd prefer to be using.

### Install Jupyter in your environment

1. In VSCode, go do the bottom "Terminal" tab
2. If you're not yet in your env, you can enter it by typing `source .virtualenv/bin/activate`
3. Once you're in your environment install Jupyter:
   `pip install jupyter`

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your help,
I already created a virtual environment (called it DataVenv) even though I forgot to activate it, now I did activate it, I can see it in the interpreter menu but even if I click on that option I still get the same problem, also I also installed Jupyter in the venv but it's not just jupyter, it's about any python program that I'm trying to run

Comment: When you're in your Terminal tab and your environment is activated, you should see: `(.virtualenv) ~`  
When you see that then run a hello_world.py type file `python hello_world.py`, does that also fail?

Next in the Terminal tab, with the environment activated, what happens when you run `jupyter notebook`? It should open your browser and a new Jupyter Notebook instance.

These two things will give you hints, if they both work then there is some configuration issue in VSCode rather than an issue with python or Jupyter. If you think it's VSCode config you can try resetting it.

Comment: both are working properly, I will try to reinstall it again (even though I already tried it, but maybe I did something wrong during the process)

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved.. I had to format my PC so now everything working :D